Console.log prints value and prints 'undefined'?
when we provide the value in the console.log, it prints the given value and provides an undefined.

why there is an undefined after printing the value. if the return type of console.log is undefined, it should print before the given value gets printed.
Can anyone explain this scenario?

"if the return type of console.log is undefined, it should print before the given value gets printed" What makes you think that?

before the execution of the value, it reads the console.log right, that means it would print undefined before value prints. Correct me if I am wrong.

The console prints the return value of the function. The return value is only returned after the function is done doing whatever it's doing; which in this case is outputting something to the console.

You're executing two console.log() statements in a single console command. This is evident because the screenshot only shows a single prompt (>).
When executing multiple statements in a single command, the console first executes the statements (in this case logging "hello" and "world"), and then prints the return value of the last statement, which is undefined.
